# Collapse table within foreach loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to make a report for invoices in which your salespersons have a total row and if you click that it shows the invoices corresponding to each sp . I'm using the foreach loop but the second row doesn't expand . I know it has to do something with the id of the tr but can't figure out why .

```
     <div id="grandparent" class="list-group-item">
                <div class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#grandparentContent" data-role="expander" data-group-id="grandparent">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li class="icon-class"></li>
                        <li>Raporti</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

<div class="collapse" id="grandparentContent" aria-expanded="true">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Agjenti</th>
                                <th>Total Polisa</th>
                                <th>Te Vlefshme</th>
                                <th>Te Pa Vlefshme</th>
                                <th>Te Vlefshme $</th>
                                <th>Te Pa Vlefshme $</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>

    @foreach (var agent in @Model.AgentsTotal.Individuals)
    {
        <tbody>
            <tr class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseone_@agent.Agjenti" data-role="expander">
                <td class="icon-class"></td>
                <td>@agent.Agjenti</td>
                <td>@agent.TotalPolisa</td>
                <td> @agent.TeVlefshme</td>
                <td> @agent.TepaVlefshme</td>
                <td> @agent.VleraTeVlefshme</td>
                <td> @agent.VleraTePaVlefshme</td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var police in agent.IndividualPolices)
            {
                <tr class="collapse collapseone_@agent.Agjenti" id="collapseone_@agent.Agjenti" aria-expanded="true" >
                    <td>
                        <a asp-controller="Polisat" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="@police.PoliceId">@police.PoliceNo</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @police.Klienti
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @police.Paketa
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @police.Valide
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
             </tbody>
     }



                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the part where my code doesn't work as wanted

```
  @foreach (var police in agent.IndividualPolices)
        {
            <tr class="collapse collapseone_@agent.Agjenti" id="collapseone_@agent.Agjenti" aria-expanded="true" >
                <td>
                    <a asp-controller="Polisat" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="@police.PoliceId">@police.PoliceNo</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @police.Klienti
                </td>
                <td>
                    @police.Paketa
                </td>
                <td>
                    @police.Valide
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

How it should work is like this sample here : 
[Sample](https://www.bootply.com/oxKYaxmDYF#)

In my case the Parent1 (in sample) collapsible row doesn't expand or collapse .

Comment: Please don't use off-site links. Make sure your question is complete enough to answer on StackOverflow. This is so that if your link disappears the question is still useful.

Comment: How are you performing the collapse/expand? Where is the code that does this? I don't see it. So no, your question is not clear enough. You've also included tags like "html" and "css" yet this question has nothing to do with CSS since no styles are included in this question.

Comment: The collapse/expand is performed on a javascript inside the view and its irrelevant to the problem as it works on collapse class and in my code the rows inheirt it. The problem is in the code above and it looks like you're more a moderator than a problem solver . Thank you for nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might be having a problems with this . When you use a foreach loop make sure the value you pass on date-target is a unique-int value . In the example above i was passing a string which date-target didn't recognize .